# Meaning - "Thank you," ... "but apologize to him."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Last November, Sri Srinivasan, a government lawyer, apologized to Justice David H. Souter for referring to him as Justice Scalia.
>
> ["Thank you," Justice Souter said, with characteristic self-deprecation, "but apologize to him."](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/12/31/politics/31mirth.html?_r=1&)
>
> "[Laughter.]"

Would someone please elucidate the meaning or subtext here? Is Justice Souter implying that the apology should be directed at Justice Scalia, because Scalia, and not Souter, is the one who would be offended? What's amusing?

Comment: Not really. Justice Souter is suggesting that the apology should be directed at Justice Scalia, because Scalia, and not Souter, is the one who has been slighted by the comparison. 'I'm not fit to tie Scalia's bootlaces' (Well, Souter's not quite going that far.) It's meant in fun. And this attitude of seeing (or at least pretending to see) others as better / more valuable / more worthy of praise than oneself is called 'self-deprecation'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Would you like to answer too?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding social status and humour, not the English language

Comment: I can't now, but I wouldn't, as I feel it's not really the sort of question the site ('for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts') is really seeking. The sister site (ELL) is aimed more at helping with fairly basic understanding. I sometimes 'answer in a comment' to try to help without undermining the integrity of ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the parenthetical sentence.

Souter is implying that having mistaken Souter for Scalia is a bigger insult to Scalia than it is to Souter to be mistaken for Scalia - a person he might admire.